# wordpress not calling peliegro functions.php?

Tags: functions, theme-development

I'm very confused with this question because I'm not really sure what is happenning, but as far as I know, my "father" functions.php is not being called.
I'm using peliegro and peliegro Child.
What I do is to call peliegro functions.php which has code to send an iOs and Android push notification everytime a new content is uploaded. I've tryed to add new content in the blog but never receive any push in my mobile phone, so I've tryed the url's that are launched in functions.php and it works perfect, I receive the push, so my conclusion is this functions.php is never called, but I have no idea why, anyone can help??

This is the code of functions.php:

```
    <?php

/**
 * Bad Weather Framework Initiation, load bootstrap
 */

require get_template_directory() . '/bw/bootstrap.php';

//remove dates
function jl_remove_post_dates() {
    add_filter('the_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('the_time', '__return_false');
    add_filter('the_modified_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_time', '__return_false');
    add_filter('get_the_modified_date', '__return_false');
    add_filter('echo(get_the_date)', '__return_false');
    add_filter('echo(get_the_time)', '__return_false');
    add_filter('echo(get_the_modified_date)', '__return_false');
} add_action('loop_start', 'jl_remove_post_dates');


//push
$entrada = '';
function wpse_18140_transition_post_status( $new, $old, $post ) {
     if ( $new === 'publish' && $new !== $old ) {
           // Your code here

$link = trim(get_permalink($post->ID));

//curl to db conexion

$url = "http://example.com/iOsPush.php";
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('host' => 'example', 'dbname' => 'dbname_user', 'user' => 'example_user','pass' => 'example_pass','link' =>$link);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$ch2 = curl_init();
$url2 = "http://example.com/androidPush.php";
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
$result2 = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);

     } 
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_18140_transition_post_status', 10, 3 );


//add a contact form if post type

function is_post_type($type)
{
    global $wp_query;
    if($type == get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)) return true;
    return false;
}

function add_post_content($content){
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home()&& is_single() && is_post_type('post'))
    {
        $content .= '[contact-form-7 id="2202" title="Formulario de contacto 1"]';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
?>
```

Comment: is other code in the file working? for example remove dates callback?

Comment: the dates are ok, it's working for the dates but not for the push, It's very confusing ...

Comment: The `functions.php` file loads just fine. First make sure your curl is working (you should be using WordPress own [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)). If doesn't work try hooking into [`publish_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) instead of `transition_post_status`

Comment: curl work like a charm. Publish post give me this error:
"Warning: Missing argument 3 for wpse_18140_transition_post_status() in /home/guiasdelsures/public_html/wp-content/themes/peliegro/functions.php on line 26"

I've only changed this line: "add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_18140_transition_post_status', 10, 3 );"

To this other: "add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpse_18140_transition_post_status', 10, 3 );"